# How to print a hash of hashes [of hashes]* as CSV in perl

Tags: perl, csv, hash-of-hashes

I want to print a hash of hashes of hashes (with an indefinable depth) as CSV.

Imagine that I have a structure of foos, bars, cars, ... where the keys of the deepest hash are pointing to a numeric scalar.

I want to print this structure to look like this:

```
foo1;bar1;car1;345
foo1;bar1;car2;25347
foo1;bar2;car1;23
foo2;bar1;car1;863
......
......
```

Does anybody know how to do this, when you're not aware of the depth of the hash-structure (there also could be additional mars and wars and so on)?

What have I tried so far?

```
sub print_csv {
    my $subj = shift;
    if ( ref($subj) eq "HASH" ) {
        for ( keys $subj ) {
            print "$_;";
            print_csv( $subj->{$_} );
        }
    }
    else {
        print "$subj\n";
    }
}
```

This is my general idea, but the keys of the hashes won't be repeated after the first one.

Thanks in advance!!!

**Edit**
I'm already using perl 5.14. My Problem is, that the keys of the hashes won't be repeated after they first appeared. My current output looks like this:

```
foo1;bar1;4
foo2;bar2;12060
bar3;24
bar1;152
foo3;bar3;1
bar1;815
```

foo2 has 3 bars (bar1, bar2, bar3), but it's name "foo2" isn't repeated in lines 3 and 4. It's the same with foo3. It has two bars (bar1 and bar3) but it's name "foo3" is missing in line 6.

Comment: This works fine on Perl v5.14 and later, where `keys` happily accepts a hashref instead of a hash. You should consider upgrading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it now, I think this is what you want:

```
sub print_csv {
    my $subj = shift;
    my $prefix = shift || "";
    if ( ref($subj) eq "HASH" ) {
        for ( keys %$subj ) {
            print_csv( $subj->{$_}, $prefix ."$_;");
        }
    }
    else {
        print "$prefix$subj\n";
    }
}
```

Data:

```
my %hash = ();
my %hash2 = ();
my %hash3 = ();

$hash3{"test3Key"}="test5";
$hash2{"test2Key"}=\%hash3;
$hash2{"test2Key2"}="test2Key2Value";
$hash{"testSimpleKey"} = "test2";
$hash{"testHashRefKey"}=\%hash2;
```

Results:

```
testSimpleKey;test2
testHashRefKey;test2Key;test3Key;test5
testHashRefKey;test2Key2;test2Key2Value
```